# Check how much left to the nearest multiple of four in PHP

Tags: php, magento-1.9

I am creating a magento website where I'm allowing to buy at least 4 products and then multiples of four. The thing I'm struggling with is 
the else statement which should give a number to the following multiple of four. For e.g. If the person has 5 products it should display "Add 3 more products to your bundle" , or if person has 10 products " Add 2 more products to your bundle". I hope I've described it well.

My code is :

```
      `<?php else: ?>
        <p class="empty"><?php echo $this->__('Add  more products to your bundle before checking out') ?></p>
          <?php endif ?>`
```

Thank you for any helpful answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for the [modulus-operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php)

```
$modulo = 11 % 4; //this will return 3 as the remainder
echo $modulo; //echos 3
if($modulo!=0){ //only execute this when items are needed
    $needed = 4 - $modulo;
    echo "you need ". $needed ." more items"; //echos "you need 1 more items
}
```

Comment: Thank you great answer . I was thinking of using modulus , but wasn't sure if it's going to work.

Comment: The more you try different things, even tho you are no sure if they work, the more you learn. Just give everything that comes to your mind a shot and then try to improve ;)

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [modulus](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) function.

```
$remainder = ($item_count % 4);
```

> $a % $b | Modulus | Remainder of $a divided by $b.

Comment: That would give '1' for an amount of 5 products. OP looks for `3`  as a result

Comment: @AxelAmthor You are correct - I didn't think about that.